# Como manter a conexão com o Sql por um longo período

Tags: sql

Minha aplicação faz o `select` na tabela **A** do servidor **1** e com o resultado do `select` é feito um `insert` na tabela **B** do servidor **2** com os dados da consulta. A rotina funciona por determinado tempo, depois tenho esta exceção:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)

Os resultados das consultas giram em torno de 50k de linhas a 96K (porém existe um caso de mais de 990k de linhas), quando chega por volta de 20k ocorre essa exceção. Seria um erro de conexão ou uma exceção do Sql ?

Comment: A conexão está sendo fechada ao término das execuções ? Ese link do SO fala sobre isso. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908512/error-19-physical-connection-is-not-usable-with-owin-access-in-azure-databa

Comment: @denis como eu faço operação descrita em quatro tabelas eu abro a conexão executo a operação das quatro tabelas e então encerro a conexão. Faço isso para não precisar fechar a conexão e abrir para cada tabela, alterando apenas o `commandText` e usando uma só conexão...

Comment: Entendi. Bom nunca passei por isso mais o pessoal diz neste outro link do SO que pode ser um cache do servidor ou algo do gênero que apenas reiniciando o servidor resolveu. Mais também tem uns comandos de fluxo que você pode testar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962927/a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-receiving-results-from-the-server

Answer (score 1):

Eu só vi isso uma vez, e era quando estava trabalhando em uma rede bem vagabunda, com o wifi caindo o tempo todo.

Trocar para o cabo me ajudou, mas no seu caso, se não houver permissão, recomendo otimizar a consulta, ou fazer ela de forma assincrona se não houver outra opção.

Comment: Como seria assíncrona?

Comment: Eu tive um problema parecia em uma aplicação web, que inseria alguns registros no SAP. As vezes o SAP demorava muito para responder, e dava timeout.  Então eu crirei um Windows Service que recebia uma msg e fazia o serviço enquanto o usuário podia seguir navegando pela aplicação.